# Десериализация массива C#

Tags: c#, serialize, filestream

Нужно провести десериализацию с фала в новый массив, как осуществить? Сериализую так:

```
int[] i = new int[10];
i[0] = 10;
...                   // Взял упрощенный массив
i[9] = -6;

BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fs, i);
        }
```

Comment: А как вы его туда сериализовали? Покажите код сериализации.

Comment: @VladD показал же

Comment: А, тьфу, и правда :)

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
int[] j;
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("data.dat"))
    j = (int[])serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

Comment: О блин точно... Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Denver: Пожалуйста!